# Paypal adaptive payment checkout page not open in mobile webview

Tags: webview, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have used PayPal adaptive payment API for parallel payment and refund payment in my mobile app. All thing is working fine.

One thing i want to ask, is it possible to view PayPal checkout page show in mobile browser view?. Because when user want to do payment of any product than PayPal api work in mobile web view and page showing as computer view.

Is it possible to view checkout page in mobile web view size?

Comment: You got any solution? we are facing same issue.

Comment: I communicated with PayPal technical support team they suggest us following update:- Hi and Thank you for contacting PayPal Merchant Technical Services.

Unfortunately, Adaptive Payments has never been mobile-optimised.  Now that the product has been deprecated, i'm afraid that no updates are planned in order to resolve this. 

As an alternative, may I recommend you contact Braintree regarding their 'Braintree for Marketplaces' offering: https://www.braintreepayments.com/ie/products/braintree-marketplace
 
If you have any further queries, please do not hesitate to respond here.
 
Thank

Comment: Thanks for comment @Pankaj. My problem is Braintree is not supported in many countries. I just asked to paypal. let see what reply they are going to give.